# 400: Missing Tracks error when attempting to remove track from Spotify playlist

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify

I'm attempting to delete a track from a test playlist I've created.  It's the third track in the playlist (ie index 2), with a Spotify id of `3PqvdKpjaxab0mWns1laKo`.  My code to do this is as follows:

```
method = "delete"
url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/"+username+"/playlists/6bhZt1Uia5pfmeL5OYDJZM/tracks"
headers = {
    'Authorization':  'Bearer ' + TOKEN, 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
params = {
    "tracks": [
        {
            "positions": [2],
            "uri": "spotify:track:3PqvdKpjaxab0mWns1laKo"
        }
    ]
}
response = requests.request(method, url=url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

However, when I run the code, the track is not deleted, and the following error message is returned: `{'error': {'message': 'Missing tracks', 'status': 400}}`

On the other hand, if I try the exact same request in the [web api](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/delete-playlist-tracks/) or using curl (as below), it works successfully.

```
curl -X DELETE "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/USERNAME/playlists/6bhZt1Uia5pfmeL5OYDJZM/tracks" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"tracks\":[{\"positions\":[2],\"uri\":\"spotify:track:3PqvdKpjaxab0mWns1laKo\"}]}"
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: the data is passed to the endpoint as data, not as parameters.  In other words, changing the last line to

```
response = requests.request(method, url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(params))
```

fixes the problem.